# Problems overriding _iterencode method on JSONEncoder that employs a generator

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to create my own custom encoder that mostly reuses the JSONEncoder behaviour:

```
BinaryJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def _iterencode(self, o, markers):
        sys.stderr.write("Calling custom _iterencode\n")
        try:
             return JSONEncoder._iterencode(self, o, markers)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
             sys.stderr.write("Got exception\n")
             return ""
```

However, I still get an unhandled UnicodeDecodeError, because once the _iterencode method is called, it cycles through its generators before returning.  What's strange is that the exception originates from the _iterencode method, but my method is nowhere in the return stack!  But my function is being called, because the "Calling custom _iterencode" messages are coming out in the Apache error_log.  How can I work around this issue without implementing the entire method from scratch?

Here is the stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/radiator/cgi-bin/ldapsearch.py", line 108, in <module>
    res.body(json.dumps(res_data, cls=BinaryJSONEncoder))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 367, in encode
    chunks = list(self.iterencode(o))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 306, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_list(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 204, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in self._iterencode(value, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 306, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_list(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 204, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in self._iterencode(value, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 309, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_dict(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 275, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in self._iterencode(value, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 306, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_list(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 204, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in self._iterencode(value, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 294, in _iterencode
    yield encoder(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only viable way to overcome this problem is to implement the whole function again, with handlers for the binary data:

from json.encoder import encode_basestring_ascii, encode_basestring

```
class BinaryJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def _iterencode(self, o, markers=None):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            try:
                o = unicode(o, "utf8")
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                o = base64.b64encode(o)

        if isinstance(o, basestring):
            if self.ensure_ascii:
                encoder = encode_basestring_ascii
            else:
                encoder = encode_basestring
            _encoding = self.encoding
            if (_encoding is not None and isinstance(o, str)
                    and not (_encoding == 'utf-8')):
                o = o.decode(_encoding)
            yield encoder(o)
        elif o is None:
            yield 'null'
        elif o is True:
            yield 'true'
        elif o is False:
            yield 'false'
        elif isinstance(o, (int, long)):
            yield str(o)
        elif isinstance(o, float):
            yield floatstr(o, self.allow_nan)
        elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
            for chunk in self._iterencode_list(o, markers):
                yield chunk
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            for chunk in self._iterencode_dict(o, markers):
                yield chunk
        else:
            if markers is not None:
                markerid = id(o)
                if markerid in markers:
                    raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
                markers[markerid] = o
            for chunk in self._iterencode_default(o, markers):
                yield chunk
            if markers is not None:
                del markers[markerid]
```

I understand the issue with the yields exiting when an exception is thrown, but why can't the superclass method be called there after without it then only calling the superclass methods?